# Unable to add an entity to Cosmos DB - Table

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to save dummy entities to my Azure Table in Cosmos DB just to check the format in which data is returned from an SDK. I used the Data explorer provided in the portal to add the following content.

[image]

However, I keep getting the error as shown on the bottom. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reproduce your issue on my side.

[image]

But switch azure [storage-explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/),it works fine.Please try it.

[image]

Anyway,you could commit feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db).

Comment: @Clinkz You're welcome! But the explorer on the portal has strange behavior.